# How to connect to mysql in my own ZF library?

Tags: database, zend-framework, connect, bootstrapping

I created my own library with path: `library/Mylib`. I have a class in `library/Mylib/` named `Acl.php` :

```
    class Mylib_Acl extends Zend_Acl{
        public $_db;

        public function init(){
            $this->_db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(
                array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'dbname' => 'mydb'
                )
            );
            Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($this->_db);
        }

public function __construct(){
        self::initRole();

    }

        public function initRole(){
            Zend_Debug::dump($this->_db);
            Zend_Debug::dump(Zend_Registry::get('db'));
            die;
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table';
                $result = $this->_db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

        }
```

`Zend_Debug::dump($this->_db)` give me : `NULL`

`Zend_Debug::dump(Zend_Registry::get('db'))` give me this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'No entry is registered for key 'db'' in /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Registry.php:147 Stack trace: #0 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Fxml/Acl.php(19): Zend_Registry::get('db') #1 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Fxml/Acl.php(62): Fxml_Acl->initRole() #2 /home/truong/public_html/test2/application/Bootstrap.php(25): Fxml_Acl->__construct() #3 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(666): Bootstrap->_initAutoload() #4 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(619): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('autoload') #5 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #6 /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #7 /home/truong/pu in /home/truong/public_html/test2/library/Zend/Registry.php on line 147
```

I did register 'db' key in my application/Bootstrap.php :

```
public function _initDb(){
         $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(
            array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
                'dbname' => 'mydb'
            )
        );
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);

        Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
    }
```

And I did have : `autoloaderNamespaces.Mylib = "Mylib_"` in application.ini

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- The init() method in your Acl class is never called (at least not in your example)
- The init() method is creating another database connection - best to reuse the one you created in the bootstrap
- You are calling initRole() statically when it is not a static method

You've not included the part of your app where you call the Acl class, which may be the cause of the error. E.g. if you were instantiating the class in your bootstrap before the database resource was setup, this would explain the error you are seeing.

You could greatly simplify your class by changing it to something like this:

```
class Mylib_Acl extends Zend_Acl{
    public $_db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
        $this->initRole();
    }

    public function init(){
        $this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    }

    [etc.]
}
```

as long as the _initDb() method in the bootstrap is run before you use the Acl class this should then be fine.